# Simple way to choose random cell from a list in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, random, indexing, google-sheets-formula

Do you have a list of names in one column and want to draw between them?

Here is the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

one character shorter solution would be:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: =offset(A1,randbetween(0,9),0) or even offset(A1,rand()*10,0) I guess but not worth a separate answer

Answer (score 4):

For this we will use two functions: [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) and [`RANDBETWEEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093507?hl=en)

If you want to randomly choose one cell between `A1` and `A10` the formula would look as follows:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

And if you decide to make more than one draw, you can type `CONTROL+R`, automatically the formula is updated within the cell, delivering a new result.